# where can i find the files of smart gwt themes and how to use a custom theme in smartgwt

Tags: smartgwt

I am looking for the files pertaining to the regular and mobile themes used by Smart GWT.

I can see that there is a "smartgwt-skins.jar" JAR file, but I cannot see the HTML/CSS/Images...

Also, how do I use my own theme, after I have created it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Arvind, There are css, html, xml and javascript classes as well as images for different skins in smartGWT and smartGWT-skins jars. If you want to use them, you need to add following code in your .gwt.xml file:

```
<inherits name="com.smartclient.theme.simplicity.SimplicityResources" />
<inherits name="com.smartclient.theme.simplicity.Simplicity" />
```

The above code is for skin named "Simpliycity". There are many other skins in the jars such as:

- Enterprise
- Enterprise Blue
- Graphite
- TreeFrog
- BlackOps

If you don't want to use any of these and make a new one on your own, then you need to define your css file and include it in the same .gwt.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still looking where to find the themes, you can find them inside the smartgwt.jar. if you are using an IDE you can search for the  .jar in the external libraries in the package explorer.

[image: smartgwt.jar tree]